# "Couldn't load PyQGIS" Error running QGIS on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, installation, ubuntu

I have installed QGis on Ubuntu 14.04 from the [QGis stable repository](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#ubuntu); it went fine with no errors reported. But when I launch QGis I get this huge window with the following message:

> Couldn't load PyQGIS. 
> Python support will be disabled.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 1, in
>     File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/**init**.py", line 35, in
>  
>       from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
>  ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/core.so: undefined symbol:
>   _ZN16QgsComposerShape12setSceneRectERK6QRectF
>
> Python version:
>   2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 23:03:41)  [GCC 4.8.2]
>
> QGIS version:
>   2.2.0-Valmiera 'Valmiera', exported
>
> Python path:
>  ['/usr/share/qgis/python',
>   u'/home/desousa/.qgis2/python',
>   u'/home/desousa/.qgis2/python/plugins',
>   '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins',
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MapScript-6.0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.8.4-py2.7.egg',
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg',
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_dateutil-2.1-py2.7.egg',
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg',
>   '/usr/lib/grass64/etc/python/grass/script', '/usr/lib/grass64/etc',
>   '/usr/lib/grass64/etc/python', '/usr/lib/grass64/lib',
>   '/usr/lib/grass64/bin', '/usr/lib/grass64/scripts',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/home/desousa/Eclipse/Workspace.Tudor/OWSLib',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
>   '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']

The packages I have installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep qgis
ii  libqgis2.2.0                                          2.2.0-1~precise1                                    amd64        QGIS - shared libraries
ii  python-qgis                                           2.2.0-3+trusty1                                     amd64        Python bindings to QGIS
ii  python-qgis-common                                    2.2.0-3+trusty1                                     all          Python bindings to QGIS - architecture-independent files
ii  qgis                                                  2.2.0-3+trusty1                                     amd64        Geographic Information System (GIS)
ii  qgis-common                                           2.2.0-3+trusty1                                     all          QGIS - architecture-independent data
ii  qgis-plugin-globe                                     2.2.0-3+trusty1                                     amd64        OSG globe plugin for QGIS
ii  qgis-plugin-globe-common                              2.2.0-3+trusty1                                     all          OSG GLOBE plugin for QGIS - architecture-independent data
ii  qgis-plugin-grass                                     2.2.0-3+trusty1                                     amd64        GRASS plugin for QGIS
ii  qgis-plugin-grass-common                              2.2.0-3+trusty1                                     all          GRASS plugin for QGIS - architecture-independent data
ii  qgis-providers                                        2.2.0-3+trusty1                                     amd64        collection of data providers to QGIS
ii  qgis-providers-common                                 2.2.0-3+trusty1                                     all          collection of data providers to QGIS - architecture-independent files
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [package list notes](http://qgis.org/debian/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages):

```
Package: libqgis2.2.0
Source: qgis
Version: 2.2.0-3+trusty1
Architecture: amd64
```

which is not what your listing says.
So either the package is broken, or your installation failed.

The package files are available at the [QGis web site](http://qgis.org/debian/pool/main/q/qgis/).

A precise package might not run on trusty.

Comment: I had to purge this package and re-install QGis. Now it starts up without errors and all the plugins are available.