# How to fix "Unable to load GdalTools plugin. The required "osgeo [python-gdal]" module is missing."

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-2, installation

When I start QGIS, it display error message: 
Unable to load GdalTools plugin.
The required "osgeo [python-gdal]" module is missing.
Install it and try again.

`Couldn't load plugin 'processing' from ['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/notroot/.qgis2/python', '/home/notroot/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools']`

[image]

I am using QGIS 2.6 and Ubuntu 12.04!

This is the packages I have installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep qgis

 ii  libqgis-analysis2.6.1            2.6.1-1precise1       QGIS - shared analysis library
 ii  libqgis-core2.6.1                2.6.1-1precise1       QGIS - shared core library
 ii  libqgis-customwidgets            2.6.1-1precise1       QGIS custom widgets for Qt Designer 
 ii  libqgis-gui2.6.1                 2.6.1-1precise1       QGIS - shared gui library
 ii  libqgis-networkanalysis2.6.1     2.6.1-1precise1       QGIS - shared network analysis library 
 ii  libqgisgrass2.6.1                2.6.1-1precise1       QGIS - shared grass library 
 ii  libqgispython2.6.1               2.6.1-1precise1       QGIS - shared Python library 
 ii  python-qgis                      2.6.1-1precise1       Python bindings to QGIS 
 ii  python-qgis-common               2.6.1-1precise1       Python bindings to QGIS - architecture-independent files 
 ii  qgis                             2.6.1-1precise1       Geographic Information System (GIS) 
 ii  qgis-common                      2.6.1-1precise1       QGIS - architecture-independent data 
 ii  qgis-plugin-globe                2.6.1-1precise1       OSG globe plugin for QGIS 
 ii  qgis-plugin-globe-common         2.6.1-1precise1       OSG globe plugin for QGIS - architecture-independent data 
 ii  qgis-plugin-grass                2.6.1-1precise1       GRASS plugin for QGIS 
 ii  qgis-plugin-grass-common         2.6.1-1precise1       GRASS plugin for QGIS - architecture-independent data 
 ii  qgis-providers                   2.6.1-1precise1       collection of data providers to QGIS 
 ii  qgis-providers-common            2.6.1-1precise1       collection of data providers to QGIS - architecture-independent files
 ii  qgis-server                      2.6.1-1precise1       QGIS server providing various OGC services
```

Update (from comment):

`dpkg -l | grep gdal` returns

```
1.10.0-1~precise2 
ii  libgdal-dev     1.10.0-1~precise2                       Geospatial Data Abstraction Library - Development files
rc  libgdal1-1.7.0  1.7.3-6ubuntu3                          Geospatial Data Abstraction Library
ii  libgdal1h       1.10.0-1~precise2                       Geospatial Data Abstraction Library
ii  python-gdal     1.10.0-1~precise2                       Python bindings to the Geospatial Data Abstraction Library
ii  python3-gdal    1.10.0-1~precise2                       Python 3 bindings to the Geospatial Data Abstraction ibrary
```

Comment: which repository did you use? Try installing python-gdal manually. It might get lost in first run.

Comment: See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95164/couldnt-load-pyqgis-error-running-qgis-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I done this:                                                sudo apt-get install build-essential python-all-dev
wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/gdal-1.11.1.tar.gz
tar xvfz gdal-1.11.1.tar.gz
cd gdal-1.11.1
./configure --with-python
make
sudo make                                                        install And after this error is same.

Comment: If you run `dpkg -l | grep gdal`, do you have a package python-gdal?

Comment: 1.10.0-1~precise2 
ii  libgdal-dev   1.10.0-1~precise2                       Geospatial Data Abstraction Library - Development files
rc  libgdal1-1.7.0  1.7.3-6ubuntu3                          Geospatial Data Abstraction Library
ii  libgdal1h   1.10.0-1~precise2                       Geospatial Data Abstraction Library
ii  python-gdal  1.10.0-1~precise2                       Python bindings to the Geospatial Data Abstraction Library
ii  python3-gdal  1.10.0-1~precise2                       Python 3 bindings to the Geospatial Data Abstraction ibrary

Comment: These files are gdal 1.10.1, that might not work with the gdal 1.11.1 you installed one step before.